# Session Management using Spring Security: Concurrent sessions

Tags: spring-security, session-management

I have developed a web application using spring security. For login it gets access from LDAP. Now I want to manage the session using spring security itself, I can see by using `authentication.getName()` I am getting the `username` and I can also get the `sessionID`.

Now I want to make sure if the same user is trying to login from the same system using some other browser he should get a message saying that he is already login in his account.

Can anyone give an idea how to achieve this ????

```xml
<security:session-management 
        invalid-session-url="/login.jsp?error=sessionExpired"
        session-authentication-error-url="/login.jsp?error=alreadyLogin">
    <security:concurrency-control 
               max-sessions="1" 
               expired-url="/login.jsp?error=sessionExpiredDuplicateLogin"
               error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" />
</security:session-management>
```

When I use this and try to login using some other browser it gives me the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed
enter code here
```

Answer (score 6):

I may be missing something, but I have tried the next configuration and it works as expected:

```xml
<!-- more configuration stuff -->

<sec:form-login login-page="/login.jsp"
    default-target-url="/defaultTarget.jsp"
    authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?error=true"
    login-processing-url="/login" always-use-default-target="true" />

<sec:session-management>
    <sec:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
</sec:session-management>
```

When I try to log in with the same user from another browser, it takes me to /login.jsp and shows the error message: `Maximum sessions of 1 for this principal exceeded`

EDIT: you also need to place this in your `web.xml`

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: I have the fsame configuration as you suggest. Plus JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl.

With all this, I log in with one browser; and then I log in again with another one. It seems the second one is logged in, and it's indeed. 

My problem is, I clik a link from the first browser I get the following exception:
`Estado HTTP 500 - PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [delete from persistent_logins where username = ?]; [blah blah]: Table 'gbt.persistent_logins' doesn't exist`.

And the table is actually dissapeared from the DB!!!
Has anyone an idea of what's going on?