# How to handle concurrent access in Java Spring?

Tags: java, spring-security

How can I handle concurrent access in Java Spring?

A different id should not be allowed for the same user.
Say:

a.        If user is logged-in using a browser (say IE), he/she should be prompted to re-login when trying to access the system using another browser (say firefox).

Comment: Why oh why? That will only frustrate the users, and won't provide any security improvement. People have several computers, tablets and phones nowadays. It's frequent to use several computers and browsers in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring Security.  Spring Security can be configured to only allow for a single concurrent session at a time.

Here is the JavaDocs:   http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/session/ConcurrentSessionFilter.html

And here's another StackeOverflow question that talks about it:  [Session Management using Spring Security: Concurrent sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467389/session-management-using-spring-security-concurrent-sessions)

Comment: i tried with the following steps:

Comment: <security:form-login login-page="/login.zhtml"
    default-target-url="/home.zul"
    authentication-failure-url="/login.zhtml?login_error=1"
    login-processing-url="/login" always-use-default-target="true" />
    <security:logout logout-url="/logout" invalidate-session="true" success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" />
<security:session-management>
    <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
</security:session-management>

Comment: i am not able to login the application

Comment: please give me the solution

Comment: I am using spring-core.my SecurityContext.xml file seems like:

Comment: <security:form-login login-page="/login.zhtml" default-target-url="/home.zul"
   authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"
   authentication-failure-url="/login.zhtml?login_error=1" />
  <security:logout logout-url="/logout" invalidate-session="true" success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" />
    <security:session-management>
            <security:concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" max-sessions="1"/>
        </security:session-management>

Comment: also in web.xml i included  this listner:

Comment: <listener>
       <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>

Comment: It is not working for me..please help me..

Comment: "SELECT ID as id,QUESTION_TEXT as questionText,OPTION_ONE as optionOne," +
        "OPTION_TWO as optionTwo," +
        "OPTION_THREE as optionThree,OPTION_FOUR as optionFour,OPTION_FIVE as optionFive," +
        "RIGHT_ANSWER as rightAnswer, PHASE as phase " +
        "FROM QUESTION_BANK " +
        "WHERE EXAM_YEAR = :examYear AND ENTRANCE_EXAM_CODE= :examCode"; This is my sql query...i want to convert this query to xml file using <dataset>,so that all test should pass using dbunit  & data should import into question_bank table...